# How to Access elemental of Object stored into ArrayList through other Class

Tags: java, class, arraylist, methods

File 1

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ShoppingCart{

  ArrayList<Items> itemList = new ArrayList<Items>();
  private static int budget;
  private static int limitWeight;
  private static int cartWeight = 0;
  private static final int tax = 10;
  private int itemCount;

  ShoppingCart(int budget, int limitWeight){
    this.budget = budget;
    this.cartWeight = limitWeight;
  }

  public ArrayList<Items> returnItems(){
    return itemList;
  }
  public int getCartWeight(){
    return cartWeight;
  }

  public int getBudget(){
    return budget;
  }
  public int getTax(){
    return tax;
  }
  public int addWeight(int itemWeight){
    return cartWeight+=itemWeight;
  }

  public boolean isOverweight(){
    if(this.cartWeight > limitWeight){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }

  public  int weightTillOverweight(){
    return limitWeight-this.cartWeight;
  }

  public void heviestItem(){

  }

  public void addItem(Items i){
    this.itemList.add(i);
  }


  public static class Items{
    private final String itemName;
    private final int itemPrice;
    private final int itemWeight;

    public Items(String itemName, int itemPrice, int itemWeight){
      this.itemName = itemName;
      this.itemPrice = itemPrice;
      this.itemWeight = itemWeight;
    }
    public String getItemName() {
      return this.itemName;
    }
    public int getItemPrice() {
      return this.itemPrice;
    }
    public int getItemWeight() {
      return this.itemWeight;
    }
  }
}
```

File 2

```
public class TestShoppingCart{
  public static void main(String[] args ){


    testAddItem();
  }
  private static ShoppingCart makeCart() {
    return new ShoppingCart(100, 50);
  }

  public static void testAddItem(){
    ShoppingCart s0 = makeCart();
    s0.addItem(new ShoppingCart.Items("name",2, 1));
    s0.addItem(new ShoppingCart.Items("names",3, 1));

  }

}
```

There is a snipped of my code, I am trying to access the variables that I just added to my arraylist through the addItem. I was trying to print the variable that I have used a getmethod but I can only get the reference number to the array. Can someone explain me how to get the Element within the ArrayList ?

Thanks ! Sorry in advance for the bad English!

Comment: Class names should be singular, unless a single instance represents multiple items.

Comment: Looking for `s0.returnItems().get(0)`?

Comment: shmosel, I have the class ShoppingCart, TestShoppingCart and Items.

Comment: System.out.print(s0.returnItems().get(0)); gives me the address and not the value

Comment: Then show what you've tried and what error you're getting. We can't help you if you don't tell us the problem.

Comment: I am just trying to access the variables, I tried doing what the comment bellow suggested but it didnt work

Comment: Still not a useful problem description.

Comment: _print the variable that I have used a getmethod but I can only get the reference number to the array_ I'm guessing you're printing an address. There is no such thing as a "reference number to the array" in this context. Provide a complete sample that reproduces your problem, as you haven't given enough information.

Comment: Yes, I wanna print the variable that I just added instead

Comment: You don't show us whether those classes are in separate files or not. We do not know what constructor is called here: `new ShoppingCart(100, 50)`.

Comment: ok, I edited the post, hopeully now it is easier to understand ! thanks for your patience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add getter methods for

```
private final String itemName;
private final int itemPrice;
private final int itemWeight;
```

this way:

```
public String getItemName() {
    return this.itemName;
}
```

and then:

```
for(int i = 0; i < s0.returnItems().size(); i++){
    System.out.println(s0.returnItems().get(i).getItemName());
    System.out.println(s0.returnItems().get(i).getItemPrice());
    System.out.println(s0.returnItems().get(i).getItemWeight());
}
```

Comment: I have the get Methods inside my Item class just like you did.
Where should I use the for loop?
Thanks!

Comment: It says that It cant find the symbol Items

Comment: Check now, please.

Comment: Just as a follow up question, just like I created a method to create a Cart, could I create one to create a bunch of items ?

Comment: Of course. The same way. I think that the class name `Item` would be better than `Items`.

Comment: ShoppingCart s0 = makeCart();
    s0.addItem(new ShoppingCart.Item("name",2.00f, 1));

woudl I have something like s0.addItem(makeItem()));